# Windows Subsystem for Linux sources.list

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

Where is the sources.list file in Windows 10 version 1607 (Anniversary Update)?

I can get it to it just fine from the cmd > bash > `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` but I can't seem to find this file in Windows 10.

A search in the file explorer did not return any results.

Comment: You may look [where is the linux filesystem located in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1067373/where-is-the-linux-subsystems-filesystem-located-in-windows-10#1344167)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\etc\apt
```

Nevermind...

Comment: The `lsxx` folder is hidden, even if you enable hidden folders in Windows. So I had to type it out in the address bar to proceed.

Comment: if it's a system folder then you also need to enable the displaying of system files and folders beside show hidden file

Comment: The location of the linux filesystem has changed in the last versions of WSL. If you have installed the Linux distributions from the Windows Store, the files are located now under `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\...\LocalState\rootfs\etc\apt`. The `...` part varies depending of the installed distribution.