# How to access the windows linux subsystems filesystem from windows?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

So, from the linux subsystem bash I can access the windows filesystem in `/mnt/c`

but I'd like to access the linux filesystem from something like explorer, is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the Linux Subsystem's filesystem located in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1067373/where-is-the-linux-subsystems-filesystem-located-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

All files can be found at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\lxss\`.
This folder is hidden, so you need to manually navigate there.

It seems to hide itself very well by closing all file handles as soon as possible but writing large files make it still occur in the Resource Monitor.

Also: Be prepared for permission issues and invisible files when you move files there (copying is no problem).

Writing files with illegal characters (such as `/` or  `\`) results in a permission error (can't write the file).

Symlinks work flawlessly (even across file systems) as long as the file system containing that symlink is capable of those, ie. linking to other file systems works but not the other way.

Comment: nice..... wonder what's going to happen when the filesystem exceeds path length or uses an illegal windows file character... or symlinks... :)

Comment: I'm wondering how well a windows GUI git client is going to deal with it

Comment: Symlinks work fine (in bash), path limits are filesystem dependent and thus not a real issue for Windows, illegal characters: depends on the filesystem. I check out some things and come back in a minute.

Comment: I added some more information regarding your comment to my answer. I haven't checked path length, though.

Comment: Not any more, with some Windows update the path has changed.

Answer (score 3):

The path has changed, in updated Windows 10 files can be found here:

```
C:\Users\WINDOWS_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\LINUX_USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally made a way to open explorer (and vscode) with actual correct folder context from inside WSL:
https://github.com/andymule/wslwin

For example, after you install this, in linux (WSL) you would just type `explorer`, and it would open windows explorer at that location.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)