# I switched Docker over to WSL2 Is it safe to delete my Hyper-V folder?

Tags: hyper-v, wsl2, docker-for-windows

I recently switched over from the legacy Docker desktop for windows(Hyper-V) to the WSL 2 based version. I am running out of space on my hard drive and noticed a folder at `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V` that is very large (> 80 GB). Is it safe to remove that?

Comment: Haven't had this scenario, but for safety I'd at least try to delete things through Hyper-V itself rather than the folder.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds How would i go about doing that?

Comment: Can you run "Hyper-V' from the Start Menu?  I've never used Docker Desktop with Hyper-V, so not 100% sure.

Comment: Don’t delete the folder but rather selectively the files belonging to Docker.

Comment: @dovidweisz What Windows version are you running?  If you are on Professional or higher, were you able to run the "Hyper-V Manager" from the Start menu?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 Enterprise. I need Admin rights to run the "Hyper-V Manager" effectively. I'll get back to this when Desktop-support gets back to me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSL doesn't use the HyperV location to save data. You can verify this by typing the below command in PowerShell as [mentioned here](https://superuser.com/a/1344167/4377)

```
(Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath}) | select DistributionName, @{n="Path";e={$_.BasePath + "\rootfs"}}
```

This should print out where the data for your WSL2 distro is saved on the drive. Once you've verified it doesn't point to the Hyper-V directory, you can delete it off.

---

It is fine to delete them by hand, if you're never going to use them. Removing the VM in Hyper V manager should also delete the VHDs, which is the safer way, but I can't recall if WSL2 install requires disabling Hyper-V, which means you can't use Hyper-V manager. If you can use Hyper-V manager by installing it from Windows features, by all means install and remove the images using that.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that the Hyper-V location is old and stale data?

Comment: Agreed that WSL does not use Hyper-V, but the question is whether it is safe to delete data left over from a Docker Desktop installation that used Hyper-V rather than WSL (after switching to WSL).  And is the correct way to do it by deleting the folder itself?  Or should Hyper-V by used to remove the images?  I tend to think that deleting Hyper-V files from outside the manager would result in Hyper-V being in a bad state, but not sure.

Comment: I updated my answer, @NotTheDr01ds. it's safe to delete if you're not using them.

Comment: @SathyajithBhat Thanks - That's what I was saying in the comments on the question itself.  It's safer to delete through Hyper-V.  And yes, Hyper-V can be enabled alongside WSL2 without any problem, assuming Windows Pro or higher. WSL2 and Hyper-V use the same underlying system at the core, but work together just fine.  I just couldn't remember if Docker Desktop using Hyper-V required Pro, but a quick search seems to confirm that it did.  So the OP should use Hyper-V Manager to delete the files.